# Processing - See through transparent 3D shapes

Tags: 3d, processing

I would like to be able to see through transparent 3D shapes.
For example, this:

```
void setup() {
    size(400, 400, P3D);
}

void draw() {
    clear();
    translate(width/2, height/2, -width/2);

    stroke(255);
    fill(0, 255, 255, 100);
    box(width);

    noStroke();
    lights();
    fill(255);
    sphere(100);

}
```

...displays this:

[image: screenshot1]

but I want this:

[image]

Note that I just added `hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST)` for the second one. I would like a solution without this because, you know, it disables the depth test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to draw the box with disabled depth test. But enable the depth test before the sphere is drawn:

```
void draw() {
    clear();
    translate(width/2, height/2, -width/2);

    hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
    stroke(255);
    fill(0, 255, 255, 100);
    box(width);

    hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
    noStroke();
    lights();
    fill(255);
    sphere(100); 
}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Do you know if this is the expected behavior of Processing, or is this a workaround for a bug? Also this works with 2 shapes, but what if the scene had hundreds of shapes?